# Windows 8 crashed and I can't do a recovery or reformat the OS

Tags: windows-8, crash

I don't know how to fix this issue before I take my computer to a repair shop but, before that, I'll try to explain my issue.
During regular web browsing and torrent downloading, suddenly, the PC froze and re-started itself. During the Recovery Mode loading, it got stuck again and again and again (Win 8 logo appears with the 3 spinning dots) ...

I tried to insert my Windows 8 CD to re-install the OS but, nothing happens when I boot.
I don't know how to get into Safe Mode either, and the BIOS is only up for a few seconds.

I have an Asus motherboard p7p5d5 I5 with 16 GB RAM and GForce 640 Graphics card.
If some one knows how to reach the recovery mode or just to install the OS from scratch, something, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Turn on your PC so that Windows starts normally, insert the DVD or USB flash drive, and then shut down your PC.

Restart your PC, and then press any key to boot from the DVD or USB flash drive.

If you restart your PC and your current version of Windows starts, you might have to open a boot menu or change the boot order in your PC's BIOS or UEFI settings so that your PC boots from the media. To open a boot menu or change the boot order, you'll typically need to press a combination of keys (such as F2, F12, Delete, Esc, etc.) immediately after you turn on your PC. For instructions on changing the boot order for your PC, check the documentation that came with your PC or go to the manufacturer's website.

If your current version of Windows still starts, try again by waiting until Windows asks you to sign in, shutdown completely, and then restart your PC again.

On the Install Windows page, enter your language and other preferences, and then tap or click Next.

Tap or click Install Windows.

On the Enter the product key to activate Windows page, enter your product key.

The product key should be on the box that the Windows 8.1 DVD came in, or in a purchase confirmation email. It looks like this: PRODUCT KEY: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX.

On the Please read the license terms page, if you accept the license terms, tap or click I accept the license terms, and then tap or click Next.

On the Which type of installation do you want? page, tap or click Custom.

On the Where do you want to install Windows? page, do one of the following:

In Windows 8.1, tap or click the partition that you want, tap or click the formatting option you want to perform if needed, and then follow the instructions.

In Windows 8, tap or click Drive options (advanced), tap or click the partition that you want to change, tap or click the formatting option you want to perform if needed, and then follow the instructions.

When you've finished formatting, tap or click Next.

Follow the instructions to finish installing Windows.

[My Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/clean-install)

Comment: Thanks i know how to install Windows, the issue is that it is getting stack on the way up,with the install and without it..

Comment: Well, in your question you asked if anyone knew how to re-install the OS, so I gave you the information to do that. How about getting into your BIOS. You stated that it's only up for a few seconds? What does that mean? The BIOS actually loads but then the system reboots or you can only see the option to get into the BIOS for a few seconds?

Comment: Yes that's right...No way to load the Win install (Restart appears)

Comment: I thing its a Hard Drive issue...

Comment: You said "Yes that's right..." which part of my previous comment was right? If you think it's a HDD issue, it's not an unreasonable assumption. Give it a shot, the worst case scenario is if it's not the HDD, you'll have a new one laying around for something else.

Comment: Ill start again...I can set the boot from CD from bios options.but the CD is not loaded and PC forced to restart...without the CD,the PC restart after the Win 8 logo appears...it that more clearly ?